# Transformation suggestions requested - multi-regression Q

Tags: multiple-regression, data-transformation

I am thawing fish - big fish.  I am looking to regress minutes(Hrs) of thaw against fish size, starting core temperatures, thaw water temperature, water speed, and species (dummy var).  Using Minitab.  I am wondering if I can tranform the attached curve in some fashion to get a better Rsq.  now at 87%.  I have tried all of the usual suspects, and they do not help.

any ideas would be helpful.

[image: Thawing profile of tuna]

Thanks

JDeBeer

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is this curve and why do you want to transform it?

Comment: I want to be able to predict thawing times based on size, water temp, and size basically.

Comment: You did not answer my question...

Comment: 1. the curve is a core temperature of a fish plotted against time.

Comment: 2.the length of time depends on the fish size, starting core temperature, water temperature. I have tried different transformations of the variable to plot a straight hoping to get a better predictive equation.  Maybe that is not the correct thing to do, but thoguth I would ask.

Comment: OK, show us your model diagnostics as well (4 plots, Residual vs Fitted, Normal Q-Q, Scale-Location and Residual vs Leverage). Depending on what software you are using there could already be a function for this.

Comment: Trying to post plots, seem unable to post

Comment: Your plots look fine except for the residual vs fitted plot, there is some weird thing going on there. Can you share your data here?